# Why some methods in C# return narrow data types when a wider data type would make more sense?

Tags: c#

I consider myself as a good mid-level .Net developer, and I’ve gotten a decent understanding of all concepts and terminologies in C# after having worked on it for the last 3+ years. However, there’s this one question I have and I apologize if it looks like a dumb and silly question. What I want to know is why some methods in the Framework Class Library return narrow data types when a wider data type would make more sense, and we have to later cast it to the data type we are interested in. I would like to give the following two examples to support my question:

1. `Label Label1 = (Label)Grid.FindControl("Label1");`
   In this example, why is FindControl returning an instance of Control type, and we have to cast it to a Label type. It could have returned an instance of Label type since we are passing a valid ID declared in the markup in the method argument.
2. `protected override object SaveViewState()`
   In this example, on object is returned which we have to cast to may be a string type.

I’m sorry once again if my question is confusing. All I want to know is why such scenarios are returning wider types when they could have returned narrow types and it could avoid us an additional step of casting to the type we want.

Comment: So what should `FindControl` return?  You say it should be `Label`, but there are *lots* of other things that could be returned.  `"Label1"` could be the ID of a `Panel` for all the compiler knows.  About the only way you could make it (arguably) better is to make the method generic, and then have the generic argument be the return type.

Comment: You don't pass it "a valid ID declared in the markup". You pass it a string. You know what it is but the compiler is not so smart.

Comment: A lot of this has come from historical methods.  e.g. before there was good variance and generics, many methods simply returned Object instead of something better.  These methods couldn't be removed once generics and better variance came along.  So, they're there because they've always been there...

Comment: @Servy and the generic return approach would have to involve the same sort of implementation there currently is, followed by a cast, so it wouldn't actually give anything different.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I'll agree in some cases, but how would generics cover either of the first case without just wrapping the cast, and the second case at all?

Comment: It does return an instance of type Label. The compile just doesn't know that. If it didn't return an instance of type Label the cast would fail

Comment: @JonHanna It wouldn't be much different, but you could write the method to allow for something like:  `Label Label1 = Grid.FindControl<Label>("Label1")`

Comment: @Servy so the only practical effect would be that you'd type `0` less characters ;) Joking aside though, it is applicable to some cases.

Comment: @JonHanna ...what Servy said :)  But, point 1 isn't possible at all based on what was described.  The compiler would have to decide what `FindControl` returned based on a string argument.  If there was an overload, it could do it that way (if overloads could differ by return type); but it doesn't have enough information to go by. You have to tell it explicitly either with cast or a type argument (generics).  Point one just just a side-effect of loose coupling...

Answer (score 5):

This because when you design a *framework* you need to operate on as *general* level as it possible, or on *abstract* level, if you wish. Returning most *possible* base class, in this case, it creates an abstraction that can support for almost anything. Imagine:

```
Label     label1 = (Label)Grid.FindControl("Label1"); 
TextBox   textBox1 = (TextBox)Grid.FindControl("TextBox1"); 
Calendar  calendar1= (Grid)Grid.FindControl("Calendar1");
```

There is only **one** method to retrieve *a control* from the `Grid`. The *caller* knows what is it exactly, so casts to the known type.

If I, like a framework designer, would like to make special methods for `Label`, `TextBox`, `Calendar`, I would need to add one method per type. I think you would agree, that it's simply unthinkable from the *framework designer* point of view. From the point of view of a developer  who should design generic infrastructure for other developers.

Comment: Furthermore, if you added a new object that derived from Control at a later time, you would also have to change the Grid class and add another method to return your new derived class

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you're a bit turned around, since "wider" is normally used for the less derived types. E.g. `Control` is wider than `Label` because the definition covers everything derived from `Control`, which includes `Label` and also other things.

As to the actual question. There are times when one can argue pros and cons of e.g. a method that is returning what is actually a `List<T>` returning it as `List<T>` or `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. There are some good principles we can apply to that decision, but there remains an advantage in both going as wide as one can remain useful with and going as narrow as one possibly can.

This doesn't apply here though. There is no way that `Control.FindControl()` could return `Label` unless it was defined to only ever return labels. That's not what it's for, it's for returning any type of control, and so the result could just as easily be a repeater or a grid.

You yourself say of `SaveViewState`, "cast to may be a string type." The answer is in that "maybe". Sure it *maybe* a string, but it *maybe* an `object[]` or a `List<string>` or a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

If it was you who was the programmer who wrote `SaveViewState`, how would you define it? You have to cover all those possibilities and more, so you'd have to define it as returning `object`.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that this `ID` is defined in the markup file does not mean at all that the type is known at compile time, worse, there is no way to validate this at all since the markup file is not part of the compilation process.

It's also unlikely that it would be possible to do something like this with a `string` identifier alone, as there is no co-variance support for return types in C# (you can't have a method called `FindControl` that returns both `Label` and `Control`).

The closest thing you could have from this is to have the IDE to generate an extension method `FindLabel1` that would then to the cast for you, but it would just be a hack just like your code, it wouldn't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 3):

> `Label Label1 = (Label)Grid.FindControl("Label1");`
>
> In this example, why is FindControl returning an instance of Control type, and we have to cast it to a Label type.

You're wrong. Method *return type* is `Control`, but returned *instance type* is `Label` (otherwise you would not be able to upcast it).

> It could have returned an instance of Label type since we are passing a valid ID declared in the markup in the method argument.

Is could and it does. But what you're really asking here is "why do I need to upcast". Because method return type is declared as `Control`, and *that* is because there's no way at all to know your control type at compile time, when variable types are resolved.

Comment: `FindControl` returns a `Control`, not an `object`.  (everything else about the post is still valid despite that error though)

Comment: and casting to a more derived type is normally called "downcasting".